# Bidirectional logic level converter with voltage regulator and 5 volt microcontroller

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, i2c, level-shifting, atmega32u4

I have to use an N-channel enhancement mode Mosfet based Bidirectional logic level converter along with a fixed 3.3 voltage regulator along with 5 volt micro controller. I am powering the low voltage side from 3.3 volt regulator and high voltage side from the 5 volt supply of micro controller board. I am not able to drive the 3.3 volt I2C sensor with this arrangement. I am getting strange results some times i get 3.3 volt from level shifter and some times i get 1.8 volt on the level shifter chanels on changing the loads.

Comment: Show the actual schematic of your setup, identify the FET, and provide some documentation of the unexpected results such as scope traces.  If you conduct static tests by driving the pins as GPIOs, what sorts of voltages do you measure?

Comment: Which logic level converter are you using? I had the same problem I believe with a certain brand.

Comment: Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your findings so far in considerable detail with a schematic containing full part numbers for ICs. The schematic tool here is easy to use, so please don't post a photo of a sketched schematic. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract.

Comment: What is the 5V MCU? What is the 3.3V sensor? How are they connected and powered (provide schematics)?